# Passing a '2 dimensional array' local variable to a class level variable

Tags: arrays, vb.net, class

I have a sub which reads an Excel file (X rows by 5 columns) and make a copy of its data into a String array called 'matrix' in VB.NET. I do need, however, to access of this array in some other subs as well. I was hoping to pass the array to a class level array variable and then retrieve info from that one instead. But I don't how to achieve this goal.

```
Public Sub ReadFromExcel()
        Dim excel As Application = New Application
        Try
            Dim wrkbook As Workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.Location) & _
        "EXCELFILE.xls")
        Dim sheet As Worksheet = wrkbook.Sheets(1)
        Dim cell As Range = sheet.UsedRange
        Dim LastRow As Long = 0
        sheet.Activate()
        With sheet
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(XlDirection.xlUp).Row
        End With
        Dim matrix(LastRow - 1, 4) As String
        For i As Integer = 2 To LastRow
            For j As Integer = 1 To 5
                matrix(i - 1, j - 1) = cell(i, j).VALUE
            Next
        Next (i)
        wrkbook.Close()
        excel.Quit()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try this:

```
Public Class Sample
    Private xlsFileContents(0,0) as String

    Public Sub ReadFromExel()
        Dim excel As Application = New Application

        Try
            'all of your code here up to "excel.quit"

            'now redim the class array to match your matrix array
            '<array>.GetUpperBound gets the integer value of the highest index in that dimension of your array.
            'It accepts a zero-bound integer to determine which dimension you are referring to.
            ReDim xlsFileContents(matrix.GetUpperBound(0), matrix.GetUpperBound(1))

            xlsFileContents = matrix

        Catch
            'your code here
        End Try
End Class
```

I tried this in a simple console application where I manually entered data into the `matrix` array, and it worked for me.